# Reference an element in a non-active carousel item

Tags: javascript, html, css, href

I have an issue with a searchbox when looking for questions within the carousel.

The search box is used to find questions in the FAQ list.

When the user clicks on a question from the searchbox, the href brings him to that specific question in the carousel. However, if I select a question which is not in the currently active item of the carousel, nothing happens. E.g. if I search 'Question 3' while being on the first tab of the carousel, I cannot find any 'Question 3' (see example in the code).

How can I solve this?

```js
//LOADER
$(window).on("load",function(){
  $(".loader-wrapper").fadeOut("slow");
});

// searchbox
function myFunction() {
  // Declare variables
  var input, filter, ul, li, a, i, txtValue;
  input = document.getElementById('myInput');
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  ul = document.getElementById("myUL");
  li = ul.getElementsByTagName('li');

  // Hide countries when no input is given
  if (input.value.length == 0) {
    ul.style.display = "none";
    return;
  } else {
    ul.style.display = "block";
  }

  // Loop through all list items, and hide those who don't match the search query
  for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
    a = li[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
    txtValue = a.textContent || a.innerText;
    if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
      li[i].style.display = "block";
    } else {
      li[i].style.display = "none";
    }
  }
}


// FAQs
const items = document.querySelectorAll(".accordion button");

function toggleAccordion() {
  const itemToggle = this.getAttribute('aria-expanded');

  for (i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    items[i].setAttribute('aria-expanded', 'false');
  }

  if (itemToggle == 'false') {
    this.setAttribute('aria-expanded', 'true');
  }
}

items.forEach(item => item.addEventListener('click', toggleAccordion));
```

```css
body{
  background-color: #cddadaff;
}
/* - - - - CAROUSEL - - - - */
.carousel-indicators li {
    background-color: #17171cff;
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    border-radius: 100%;
}

.carousel-indicators {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -100px;
}

#FAQlist {
  padding: 6% 15% 2%;
}

#FAQs {
  padding-bottom: 450px;
}

/* - - - - Searchbar - - - - */
#myInput {
  background-position: 10px 12px;
  /* Position the search icon */
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  /* Do not repeat the icon image */
  width: 100%;
  /* Full-width */
  font-size: 16px;
  /* Increase font-size */
  padding: 12px 20px 12px 40px;
  /* Add some padding */
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  /* Add a grey border */
  margin-bottom: 12px;
  /* Add some space below the input */
  font-weight: lighter;
}

#myUL {
  /* Remove default list styling */
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

#myUL li {
  margin: 0px;
}

#myUL li a {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  /* Add a border to all links */
  margin-top: -1px;
  /* Prevent double borders */
  background-color: #f6f6f6;
  /* Grey background color */
  padding: 12px;
  /* Add some padding */
  text-decoration: none;
  /* Remove default text underline */
  font-size: 18px;
  /* Increase the font-size */
  color: black;
  /* Add a black text color */
  display: block;
  /* Make it into a block element to fill the whole list */
}

#myUL li a:hover:not(.header) {
  background-color: #eee;
  /* Add a hover effect to all links, except for headers */
}

/* Style the search field */
form.example input[type=text] {
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 17px;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  float: left;
  width: 80%;
  background: #f1f1f1;
}

/* - - - - FAQ - - - - */
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Hind:300,400&display=swap');
 * {
     box-sizing: border-box;
}
 *::before, *::after {
     box-sizing: border-box;
}

 .containerFAQ {
     margin: 0 auto;
     padding: 0;
     width: 80%;
}
 .accordion .accordion-item {
     border-bottom: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
}
 .accordion .accordion-item button[aria-expanded='true'] {
     border-bottom: 1px solid #03b5d2;
}
 .accordion button {
     position: relative;
     display: block;
     text-align: left;
     width: 100%;
     padding: 1em 0;
     color: #7288a2;
     font-size: 1.15rem;
     font-weight: 400;
     border: none;
     background: none;
     outline: none;
}
 .accordion button:hover, .accordion button:focus {
     cursor: pointer;
     color: #03b5d2;
}
 .accordion button:hover::after, .accordion button:focus::after {
     cursor: pointer;
     color: #03b5d2;
     border: 1px solid #03b5d2;
}
 .accordion button .accordion-title {
     padding: 1em 1.5em 1em 0;
}
 .accordion button .icon {
     display: inline-block;
     position: absolute;
     top: 18px;
     right: 0;
     width: 22px;
     height: 22px;
     border: 1px solid;
     border-radius: 22px;
}
 .accordion button .icon::before {
     display: block;
     position: absolute;
     content: '';
     top: 9px;
     left: 5px;
     width: 10px;
     height: 2px;
     background: currentColor;
}
 .accordion button .icon::after {
     display: block;
     position: absolute;
     content: '';
     top: 5px;
     left: 9px;
     width: 2px;
     height: 10px;
     background: currentColor;
}
 .accordion button[aria-expanded='true'] {
     color: #03b5d2;
}
 .accordion button[aria-expanded='true'] .icon::after {
     width: 0;
}
 .accordion button[aria-expanded='true'] + .accordion-content {
     opacity: 1;
     max-height: 60em;
     transition: all 200ms linear;
     will-change: opacity, max-height;
}
 .accordion .accordion-content {
     opacity: 0;
     max-height: 0;
     overflow: hidden;
     transition: opacity 200ms linear, max-height 200ms linear;
     will-change: opacity, max-height;
}
 .accordion .accordion-content p, li {
     font-size: 1rem;
     font-weight: 300;
     margin: 2em 0;
   color: #8f8f8f;
}


/* dividers */
.heading-1 {
  font-family: "PTSerif-Regular", serif;
        font-size: 28px;
        letter-spacing: 0.08em;
        font-weight: 300;
        color: #17171cff;
        text-shadow: 0 1px 1px #FFFFFF;
}

.divider-1 {
        border-bottom: 1px solid #96c5b0ff;
        background-color: black;
        height: 1px;
        margin: 0.5em 0px 1.5em;
}

.divider-1 span {
        display: block;
        width: 444px;
        height: 1px;
        background-color: #17171cff;
}

.divider-2 {
        border-bottom: 1px solid #96c5b0ff;
        background-color: black;
        height: 1px;
        margin: 0.5em 0px 1.5em;
}

.divider-2 span {
        display: block;
        width: 486px;
        height: 1px;
        background-color: #17171cff;
}

.dividerline {
  padding: 0 10% 0 10%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:ital,wght@0,300;0,400;0,500;0,600;0,700;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,600;1,700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=PT+Serif:ital,wght@0,400;0,700;1,400;1,700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.10.2/css/all.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.10.2/css/v4-shims.css">

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <title></title>
</head>

<body>

  <!-- SearchBar -->

  <section id="FAQlist">
    <input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Type a question..">
    <ul id="myUL" style="display: none">
      <li><a href="#accordion-button-1">Question1?</a></li>
      <li><a href="#accordion-button-2">Question2?</a></li>
      <li><a href="#accordion-button-3">Question3?</a></li>
      <li><a href="#accordion-button-4">Question4?</a></li>
      <li><a href="#accordion-button-5">Question5?</a></li>
      <li><a href="#accordion-button-6">Question6?</a></li>
    </ul>
  </section>


  <!-- FAQs -->

  <section id="FAQs">
    <div class="dividerline">
      <h1 class="heading-1">Frequently asked questions</h1>
      <div class="divider-1"> <span></span>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div id="slider" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="5000">
      <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#slider" class="active" data-slide-to="0"></li>
        <li data-target="#slider" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        <li data-target="#slider" data-slide-to="2"></li>
      </ol>

      <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="carousel-item active">
          <div class="containerFAQ">
            <div class="accordion">
              <div class="accordion-item">
                <button id="accordion-button-1" aria-expanded="false"><span class="accordion-title">Question1?</span><span class="icon" aria-hidden="true"></span></button>
                <div class="accordion-content">
                  <p>Answer1</p>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="accordion-item">
                <button id="accordion-button-2" aria-expanded="false"><span class="accordion-title">Question2?</span><span class="icon" aria-hidden="true"></span></button>
                <div class="accordion-content">
                  <p>Answer2</p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="carousel-item">
          <div class="containerFAQ">
            <div class="accordion">
              <div class="accordion-item">
                <button id="accordion-button-3" aria-expanded="false"><span class="accordion-title">Question3?</span><span class="icon" aria-hidden="true"></span></button>
                <div class="accordion-content">
                  <p>Answer3</p>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="accordion-item">
                <button id="accordion-button-4" aria-expanded="false"><span class="accordion-title">Question4?</span><span class="icon" aria-hidden="true"></span></button>
                <div class="accordion-content">
                  <p>Answer4</p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="carousel-item">
          <div class="containerFAQ">
            <div class="accordion">
              <div class="accordion-item">
                <button id="accordion-button-5" aria-expanded="false"><span class="accordion-title">Question5?</span><span class="icon" aria-hidden="true"></span></button>
                <div class="accordion-content">
                  <p>Answer5</p>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="accordion-item">
                <button id="accordion-button-6" aria-expanded="false"><span class="accordion-title">Question6?</span><span class="icon" aria-hidden="true"></span></button>
                <div class="accordion-content">
                  <p>Answer6</p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>

  </section>

</body>

<script src="switch.js" charset="utf-8"></script>

</html>
```

Comment: @AlonEitan done, thanks for the suggestion - didn't do this before as for some reason the carousel slide buttons are not appearing when I copy the code here, but it's not a main issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you'd need to make the relevant 'panel' of the carousel active when selecting a question.

So, if we're on 'panel 1' which contains Question 1 & 2, and you select 'Question 3' from the search bar, you would need to make panel 2 'active' (via the active class) and then do what you're currently doing to focus on Question 3

Comment: Thank you, this is helpful. I tried doing:                                                                           `<li><a data-target="#slider" data-slide-to="1" href="#accordion-button-3">Question3?</a></li>`                  In this way, when I click on Question3, my carousel slides to the relevant page but it does not find Question3 (basically the href is ignored). Is there any way to say FIRST slide to the relevant page and THEN href the specific question? Obviously with a single click..

Comment: So you're currently just using HTML - you'd likely want to handle this via JavaScript. Adding in an `onClick` handler to your `<a>` tag which adds/removes the `active` class from the relevant panels/pages, then follows the link to the question number.